# Networkx, get all in_edges of a node

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I use `in_edges` method as described in doc to get all incoming edges to a node `G[myIndex]` in a DiGraph, but`for u, v, data in G.in_edges(G[maxIndex], data=True):` actualy gives me all out_edges. Not my desired output.

When I try `G.out_edges` it gives me all edges coming from all out_edges(like one step further from the desired output). Is there something I'm missing in passing my desired node to the `nbunch` parameter? It seems like a bug to me, but in that case it would be easy to google it, so I think I'm wrong.

[image: screen]
In the image, it can be seen at the right side, that in_edges of edge 0 is giving out edges as seen at left side... it can be also seen, that the in_degree is 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `G[maxIndex]` does. It will actually give you the **out-edges** of node `maxIndex` and then getting the **in-edges** from that bunch of nodes.

If you simply want the in-edges of a given node you can do `G.in_edges(maxIndex, data=True)`. Like so:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(2, 1, 3.0), (3,1, 5.0), (4, 1, -1.0), (4, 2, 8.0)])
maxIndex = 1  # Here
for u, v, data in G.in_edges(maxIndex, data=True):
    print(u,v,data)
```

Output:

```
2 1 {'weight': 3.0}
3 1 {'weight': 5.0}
4 1 {'weight': -1.0}
```